# How to create a directory anywhere in Java?

Tags: java, file, io, directory

How can you create a directory anywhere on your hard drive using Java?  For Example, I would like to create a folder in the home folder of the computer.  If I use this code:

```
File file = new File("~/test");
if (!file.exists()) {
  try {
    folder.mkdirs();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There was an error: \n"+e, "Error!", 1);
  }
}
```

it creates a folder name "~" and a folder inside that named "test" in the directory my project is in.

How can i get Java to create the folder in my home folder?

Thanks!

Comment: `~` is not going to be expanded by most (any?) Java APIs.

Comment: `~` is resolved by the shell (e.g. Bash).  You'll need to use `/home/xyz/test`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the user directory path by getting the [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) "user.home"

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Comment: Yes, this is the idea of the properties, allowing OS portability.

Comment: If I begin the path with a "/", will Java take that as an absolute path to the directory?

Comment: In unix, yes. didn't try it on windows but i guess you'll get FileNotFound exception

Comment: And on Windows if I start the path with "C:\\"  it will take that as the absolute path?

Comment: Yes, the same goes for d:\\ etc.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is resolved by the shell (e.g. Bash), not by Java (AFAIK).  You'll need to use `/home/xyz/test`.

Comment: So if I begin the path with a "/", Java will take that as an absolute path to the directory?